# Angular Js combine a fixed ng-class with an expression in same tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a tag:

```
<body ng-cloak class="foobar" ng-class="{'fixed-header': settings.isFixed}">
```

In another similar project I have a similar:

```
<body ng-cloak class="foobar" ng-class="routeClassName">
```

How can I apply both the `routeClassName` **and** the conditional class?

I have tried

```
<body ng-cloak class="foobar" ng-class="{'routeClassName','fixed-header': settings.isFixed}">
```

and similar, but it throws an error.  So I guess my syntax is off....

Comment: sort of hacky, but 

`<body ng-cloak class="foobar" ng-class="{'routeClassName': true,'fixed-header': settings.isFixed}">`

could work

Comment: Ah.  Seems odd I'd have to make them both conditionals.

Comment: I completely agree, but seems to be A way to do it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are two ways to accomplish this:

First being, just have Angular interpolate the value since it is just the class name string anyway and then use `ngClass` for your conditional:

```
<body ng-cloak class="foobar {{routeClassName}}" ng-class="{'fixed-header': settings.isFixed}">
```

Second being, use true in the statement you have tried:

```
<body ng-cloak class="foobar" ng-class="{'routeClassName': true, 'fixed-header': settings.isFixed}">
```

I would lean toward the first option since `ngClass` is meant for conditional classes based on expressions.

Comment: 'routeClassName': true -> this is completely wrong. In this case you just literally get routeClassName as your class name, which is presumably useless. It's not interpreted as an angular variable.

Comment: @downhand The first example uses a scope variable to interpolate the value of a variable on your scope, and use the value as the class name. The second example is the literal string of the class name. This is desired behavior (you would obviously have to swap out the name for your own scenario).

Comment: the whole point of this question is that you don't know the name, it's in a variable, otherwise you would simply put it into class, why bother with ng-class.

Comment: You are exactly right. Which is why I specified not to use that approach. You would only use ngClass for setting classes based on expressions. The value of true is a valid expression, albeit not best practice. It was purely there for demonstration purposes, and to show why the original ngClass example in the question was not working. This is why interpolation is the best way to go in this case.

Answer (score 5):

A better solution for more recent versions of angular (starting with 1.4.0, possibly earlier) is to add the class via the array notation of ng-class:

```
<body class="foobar" 
      ng-class="[{'fixed-header': settings.isFixed}, routeClassName]">
```

An working example:

```js
angular.module('test',[]);
```

```css
.blue{
background: blue;
}

.red {
  border: 10px solid red;
  
}

.green{
  border: 10px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="test"
      ng-class="[{'blue': boolVar}, strVar]">


  <button type="button"
          ng-click="boolVar=!boolVar;">Toggle Bool ({{boolVar}})</button>
  
  <input type="text" 
         ng-init="strVar='green';"
         ng-model="strVar">
</body>
```

Comment: Recent as in what version?

Comment: @Steve: I tested it with angular 1.4.0, but it also might work with one of the later 1.3er versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary statement and string concatenation to get the desired effect:

```html
<body ng-cloak class="foobar" ng-class="(settings.isFixed ? 'fixed-header ' : '') + routeClassName">
```

Make sure you add the space after the conditional class name so the concatenation works properly.